# paypal how to use secret and secret token

Tags: php, paypal

I am new in paypal.  Now I am making the merchant store.

I get the permission using Third-Party Permissions Using the Permissions Service.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/permissions-service/ht_permissions-invoice/

So I get the token and secret token.   But I am not sure how I should do.

How can I check out?     I can check out using  secret and client id.  But I think token and secret token are not same.  How can I check out?  Please help me.